Tensorflow Object Detection API installation issues
I am trying to install tensorflow object detection API using this link in my Ubuntu PC.
My goal is to use MobileNet SSD for object detection.
My tensorflow version is 2.13.1. I was able to install the object detection API by following this link. But when I run a sample program to test the installation, I am getting 'ModuleNotFoundError: tensorflow.python.keras.layers.preprocessing and other issues related to version compatibility like AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'.
I tried downgrading the tensorflow version but still got similar issues.
How can I solve these issues...Thanks in advance

downgrade numpy - in their new release the types changed

I dwongraded both numpy and tensorflow and it is working now.. Thank you

downgrade numpy to a version lower than 2.0 - in their new release the types changed
